# excessive green color extraction implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

i want to segment image pixels into vegetation and Non vegetation. For this excessive green color extraction algorithm is developed.the algorithm is shown below.

Outimage (x,y,z) = inimage (x,y,z)

if { inimage (x,y,r) < (x,y,g) inimage (x,y,b) < (x,y,g) }

outimage(x,y,z) = 0 otherwise*

where outimage (x,y,z) is the output image after excessive green segmentation saved in jpg format, inimage(x,y,z) is the image acquired by an camera, x is the no of pixels in each row, y is the no of pixels in each column and z is the primary color plane for red the z is equal to 1, for green the z is 2 and for blue the z is 3.

i am not getting how to implement this so please help me to implement it.or just give some rough idea or suggestion how i can implement it.

input image:

[image: input image]

output:

i want the output to be in this format after applying above mentioned algorithm

[image]

Comment: You've got the algorithm description in your question: is it the Matlab syntax you need help with? Please be more specific with your query.

Comment: Are you able to record the infra-red channel? It is normally a good discriminant for vegetation - try Googling `NDVI` or *Normalised Difference Vegetation Index*.

Comment: @MattG yes it is matlab syntax i need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a 2D mask and then use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to apply it to all color components (third-dim slices):

```
inimage = imread('filename'); %// type uint8
mask = inimage(:,:,1)<inimage(:,:,2) & inimage(:,:,3)<inimage(:,:,2); %// 2D mask
outimage = bsxfun(@times, inimage, uint8(mask)); %// apply mask replicated along 3rd dim
```

[image]

Comment: mask = inimage(:,:,1)<inimage(:,:,2) & inimage(:,:,3)<inimage(:,:,2); can you please explain this ?inimage(:,:,1)does it refer to R pixel??inimage(:,:,2)does it refer to G pixel??

Comment: Yes, `inimage(:,:,1)` is the R component, 2 is G, 3 is B

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to convert the image to [HSV colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) if you aren't familiar with it, it converts the RGB values to Hue (color), Saturation(how vivid the color is), ~brightness(the illumination level). The nice thing about this is that you can look for the same color in all lighting conditions.

Other than how we obtain our mask (using green hues) it's the exact same process as the rgb version took

```
inimage = imread('plants.png');
hsv_im = rgb2hsv(inimage);

%plots only the hues so we can get an idea of what to segment out
hue_channel = 1;
figure(1)
imshow(hsv_im(:,:,hue_channel));   %displays only the hue channel/layer
colormap(hsv)            %uses the hue colormap
colorbar                 %displays the colorbar

%masks the greenish regions (this is subjective)
mask = hsv_im(:,:,hue_channel) < 0.5 & hsv_im(:,:,hue_channel) > 0.2;

%applies the mask to all 3 color layers
outimage = bsxfun(@times, inimage, uint8(mask));
figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(inimage);title('original image')
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(outimage);title('segmented image')
```

[image]
[image]